# Gitlab runner IP Sans issue during registration

Tags: gitlab, certificate, ssl-certificate, x509certificate2

I have Virtual Box with Gitlab instance and I'm trying to register on the same machine gitlab-runner, during that I'm getting issue about IP Sans

VM: https://bitnami.com/stack/gitlab/virtual-machine

Process
[image]

I **think** verifying certificate is successful (please correct)

[image]

Also what I have done also

1. added "**subjectAltName=IP:192.168.8.6**" to **/etc/ssl/openssl.cnf**
2. Generated cert and key in **/etc/gitlab-runner**
   [image]
3. Copied these 2 to: **/etc/gitlab/trusted-certs/**

Doing also solution from below also doesn't help
[Gitlab-CI runner: ignore self-signed certificate](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44458410/gitlab-ci-runner-ignore-self-signed-certificate)

[image]

Any ideas how I can further debug? Any help appreciated

Answer (score 2):

From this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44458410/gitlab-ci-runner-ignore-self-signed-certificate)

Step1 edit ssl configuration on the GitLab server (not the runner)

```
+sudo nano /etc/pki/tls/openssl.cnf
# find line
[ v3_ca ]
subjectAltName=IP:192.168.1.1 <---- Add this line. 192.168.1.1 is your GitLab server IP.
```

Step2 Re-generate self-signed certificate on the GitLab server (not the runner)

```
cd /etc/gitlab/ssl
sudo openssl req -x509 -nodes -days 3650 -newkey rsa:2048 -keyout /etc/gitlab/ssl/192.168.1.1.key -out /etc/gitlab/ssl/192.168.1.1.crt
sudo openssl dhparam -out /etc/gitlab/ssl/dhparam.pem 2048
sudo gitlab-ctl restart
```

Step3 Copy the new CA to the GitLab CI runner in /etc/gitlab-runner/certs/

Step4 Register your runner

```
gitlab-runner register --tls-ca-file="$CERTIFICATE"
```

this work for me.

Answer (score 0):

> For those errors like:
>
> - x509: certificate is not valid for any names, but wanted to match gitlab.example.com
> - x509: certificate relies on legacy Common Name field, use SANs instead
> - ...

I am running gitlab server 15.7.1 docker container from my laptop (following [The Official Install Guide - With docker-compose](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/install/docker.html#install-gitlab-using-docker-compose)), and installed a gitlab runner at that laptop host too.

In my case, the self-signed certificate should be re-requested manually according with the following steps:

1. Entering the running gitlab container:

   ```bash
   docker compose exec web bash
   ```
2. In container, copy the `openssl.cnf` to /etc/gitlab/ssl so that I can edit it from host machine:

   ```bash
   cp /opt/gitlab/embedded/ssl/openssl.cnf /etc/gitlab/ssl/
   ```
3. At host, Modify `openssl.cnf` to add new line into `v3_ca` section:

   ```bash
   subjectAltName=DNS:gitlab.example.com
   ```

   NOTE that a DNS name needed instead of IP
4. In container, copy back the file:

   ```bash
   cp /etc/gitlab/ssl/openssl.cnf /opt/gitlab/embedded/ssl/
   ```
5. In container, recreate x509 req and restart gitlab services to sign the gitlab server certificate again:

   ```bash
   cd /etc/gitlab/ssl
   openssl req -x509 -nodes -days 3650 -newkey rsa:2048 -keyout /etc/gitlab/ssl/gitlab.local.key -out /etc/gitlab/ssl/gitlab.local.crt
   openssl dhparam -out /etc/gitlab/ssl/dhparam.pem 2048
   gitlab-ctl restart
   ```
6. Now, `gitlab-runner register` should be ok.

   ```bash
   gitlab-runner register --tls-ca-file="$CERTIFICATE"
   ```

Lucky to anyone.